# Remove extra space after ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout

I am trying to remove extra space after the listview builder but i am not successful I tried different approaches like I wrapped my listview.builder with MediaQuery.removePadding and set the padding value to zero I also set the padding for the listview.builder to zero as well but i am not getting the required output. I don't know where i am making the mistake.

Here is the code:

```
SizedBox(
    width: widget.isDialog ? 600 : double.infinity,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5,
    child: ThemeConfig.selectFilterAsCheckBox
        ? Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: tags.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return CheckboxListTile(
                        value: tempSelectedTags.contains(tags[index].id),
                        onChanged: (e) {
                          setState(() {
                            if (tempSelectedTags.contains(tags[index].id)) {
                              tempSelectedTags.remove(tags[index].id);
                            } else {
                              tempSelectedTags.add(tags[index].id);
                            }
                          });
                        },
                        title: Text(
                          tags[index].name,
                          style: !tempSelectedTags.contains(tags[index].id)
                              ? textTheme.labelMedium?.copyWith(
                                  color: ThemeConfig.colorgreen)
                              : textTheme.titleSmall?.copyWith(
                                  color: ThemeConfig.colorgreen),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
                child: PrimaryButton(
                  title: Apply,
                  onPressed: () {
                    viewModel.setting(tempSelectedTags);
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
```

Comment: Can you simplify the widget, data  is unkown here.

Comment: I think the problem is that your ListView is nested within the SizedBox which has a constant size of `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5`. Therefore, even if there was only one element within the List, the ListView would still seem to take more space than needed while in reality it probably is the SizedBox filling all that empty space. I've not worked with Flutter in the past two months due to university but I guess what you could try instead of the SizedBox is a Container or Flexible or something like that.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh thanks for your response. Yes i think its a dialog when i click the filter button this window popup which you can see in the output

Comment: @Samaranth Yeah i need that height for small devices and its works fine on a small devices like iPhones.

Comment: Ok you like to have flexible height dialog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include `shrinkWrap: true,` on listView this will solve,

```dart
Flexible(
  child: ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
```

But I will prefer increasing item length by one.

```dart
ListView.builder(
  physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
  itemCount: itemLength + 1,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (index == itemLength) {
      return Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 11),
            child: Text("BTN")),
      );
    }
    return CheckboxListTile(
      value: true,
      onChanged: (e) {},
      title: Text(
        "tags[index].name",
      ),
    );
  }),
```

Comment: the problem with  shrinkWrap: true, is that it moving the button up now i have that empty space after the button

Comment: Remove `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5,`

Comment: if you fails , let me know by adding sample-full dialog snippet

Comment: it's not working it just moving the button up close to the checkbox (also removed the height) but now empty space is below the button. i don't know how to add the image in the checkbox i am sorry I am completely new to StackOverflow and also Flutter

Comment: you can create a sample widget and put on dialog that will reproduce the same issue

Comment: 2nd approach worked for me...thanks

Answer (score 2):

To remove extra space after ListView.builder , you can do like this :

```
child: ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `remove the SizedBox height`, set `shrinkWrap: true` in the ListView.builder and set `physics :  NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()`

Your code will be

```
SizedBox(
    width: widget.isDialog ? 600 : double.infinity,
    child: ThemeConfig.selectFilterAsCheckBox
        ? Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: tags.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return CheckboxListTile(
                        value: tempSelectedTags.contains(tags[index].id),
                        onChanged: (e) {
                          setState(() {
                            if (tempSelectedTags.contains(tags[index].id)) {
                              tempSelectedTags.remove(tags[index].id);
                            } else {
                              tempSelectedTags.add(tags[index].id);
                            }
                          });
                        },
                        title: Text(
                          tags[index].name,
                          style:!tempSelectedTags.contains(tags[index].id)
                              ? theme.textTheme.labelMedium?.copyWith(
                                  color: ThemeConfig.colorTertiary)
                              : theme.textTheme.titleSmall?.copyWith(
                                  color: ThemeConfig.colorTertiary),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: sdPaddingMedium),
                child: SdPrimaryButton(
                  title: appLocalizations.btnApply,
                  onPressed: () {
                    viewModel.setTags(tempSelectedTags);
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )
```

Comment: thanks for your response .. i tried that it's only moving the apply button up now the empty space is below the button and i am getting this behaviour by setting the  shrinkWrap: true,

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to understand how Alertdialog works.  The Flexible widget must be removed and the list must be scrollable. Here is a quick answer.

```
showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) {
                return AlertDialog(
                  title: Text('Title'),
                  content: SizedBox(
                    width: 600,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.5,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: tags.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return CheckboxListTile(
                            title: Text(tags[index]),
                            value: false,
                            onChanged: (e) {},
                          );
                        }),
                  ),
                  actions: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      child: Text('Apply'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              },
            )
```

The output is as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use itemExtent property of Listview.builder
Flexible(
child: ListView.builder(
itemExtent:tags.length+20,
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: const ScrollPhysics(),